# Struggle with fetch() in Vue.Js + GitHub API (octokat.js)

Tags: javascript, github, vue.js, github-api, octokat.js

(Beginner here)

I'm trying to create an app in Vue.js that would let me interact with GitHub API. I tried to use [vue-github-api](https://gitlab.com/clorichel/vue-github-api) at first, but because of troubles working with pagination I switched to [octokat.js](https://github.com/philschatz/octokat.js).

I tried to use the same template that was suggested in vue-github-api docs and just switch to the octokat.

For brevity I'll include this small sample:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        {{ user.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      userData: {},
      issuesList: {}
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    var Octokat = require('octokat')
    var octo = new Octokat({
      token: 'xxxxx'
    })

    octo.user.fetch(function (e, val) {
      this.userData = Object.assign({}, val)
      // or this.userData = val (not sure, which is correct)
    })
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      if (this.userData) {
        return this.userData
      }
      return 'Uh-oh...'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'userData' of undefined
```

If I would do this:

```
this.userData = octo.user.fetch()
```

Then if i console.log it I get this:

[[image: console.log output]]

I just can't seem to be able to get the desired output out of the "fetch" command.

Has anybody dealt with something similar, or did you spot a glaring error?

Comment: Try changing `octo.user.fetch(function (e, val) {` to an arrow function. Looks like this: `octo.user.fetch((e, val) => {`.

Comment: @wing It actually does the trick! How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the code fetching from the GitHub API:

```
octo.user.fetch(function (e, val) {
  this.userData = Object.assign({}, val)
  // or this.userData = val (not sure, which is correct)
});
```

Inside your callback function you are attempting to assign to `this.userData` however it is not working.

**What you have to look at here is what is `this` referring to?**

You are assigning `this.userData` inside the callback to `octo.user.fetch`. As a result `this` is not bound to your Vue instance – it would be bound to the function calling it or in your case `undefined` because the transpiler most likely added a `'use-strict'` pragma.

**What can I do about this?**

In ES6 we have [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions do not have `this` bound to it, therefore `this` is still referring to your Vue instance.

```
octo.user.fetch((e, val) => {
  this.userData = Object.assign({}, val)
});
```

**Further reading**

- **[You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes, Chapter 1: `this` Or That?](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)**
- **[You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes, Chapter 2: `this` All Makes Sense Now!](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)**
- [`this` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thank you very much for the write-up! Funniest thing is that I started reading YDKJS some time ago, but I'm at the second book atm. Makes more sense now and will make much more when I finally get to the third book.